# Can't get output from the line

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I have been struggling to get the output from the line, just starting to learn python on coursera and have been stuck on this exercise.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else :
        x = line.find(':')
        y = line.find(' ',x)
        z = line.find(' ',y)
        num = line[y+1:z]
        azz = float(num)
        total = total + azz
        count = count + 1

print(azz)
print("Done")
```

for some reason I can't print azz or num.
I did come up with a different solution which looks like this:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
total = 0 
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else :  
        x = line.find(' ')
        y = line.find(' ',x)
        num = line[x+1:]
        azz=float(num)
        count = count + 1
        total = total + azz
                
        
print(azz)
```

And now it works. I can't figure out why giving ending index is making this problem.
In this case
`num = line[x+1:]` doesn't create any issue because there is not anything on the same line after numbers, however if there was some things written on the same line after that wouldn't it be a problem?(because I only wanted to extract floating points)
Or the reason it wasn't giving me a number was because there was nothing written after number on the same line and giving it an end index wasn't making sense to python?
I hope I articulated my question well.
In the first version it was giving me NaN(not a number error)

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: It wasn't giving me any traceback errors, wasn't showing the numbers

Comment: You should add an example line to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.